# How to disable cache for authenticated users?

Tags: django, authentication, caching

My home page is the same for everyone except the navbar which displays the user's username.

I recently applied caching to my entire site using the following :

```
MIDDLEWARE += [
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
]

# CACHING
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
        'LOCATION': 'C:/Site/_cache',
    }
}

CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS = 21600 # 6 hours
```

Unfortunately, the site will now sometimes cache a version of the page including the username, meaning the site will display for some users with other people's usernames. Not ideal.

What is the best way to deal with this ? Can I exclude this part of the template from my cache ? **Or can I just say that caches aren't used for authenticated users** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can apply [template fragment caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching) to cache parts of the template using different keys. For example, to cache a separate navbar for each authenticated user for 1 hour, structure your `base.html` as follows:

```
{% load cache %}
...
{% cache 3600 navbar request.user.username %}
    Your username is {{ user.username }}
{% endcache %}
...
{% cache 3600 body %}
   ... the rest of the template which is common for all users ...
{% endcache %}
```

Comment: I was using site-wide caching which seems not appropriate for my use case, and as you said I should be using template fragment caching

I decided to not cache the navbar at all, since its performance load is trivial, but am caching the slow process instead of the entire site.

Thanks !